# Is there an method in Android which equivalent to applicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: android, android-activity

I try to use onStart() or onResume() at first. However, there are two drawbacks to use them.

1, If I start another activity and dismiss it later, as follow. (Kind of like modal present a new viewcontroller and then dismiss it)

```
private void dismiss() {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
   intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
}
```

onResume() will still be called

2, I can't reuse the same login in other activity.

Therefore, I wonder if there is an method in Android is exactly the same as - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application in Android

Comment: What do you try to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bring the `MainActivity` to the front using your `dismiss()` code, you can detect this in `MainActivity.onNewIntent()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if ((intent & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
        // I've been brought to the FRONT by another activity
    }
}
```

Does this help? I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use onRestart() Method. This method is only called when your app enters to foreground from background.

**Similarity in both of these methods :**

Its similar to appDidBecomeActive in "Some Cases". Whenever you go to background i.e. from Activity to Home Screen then onPause() followed by onStop() method is called. And then you resume back to app in android then onRestart() followed by onPause() methods are called.

Lifecycle in iOs while going background to homescreen : (App Delegate Life Cycle Methods)
appWillEnterForeground -> appDidBecomeActive

Lifecycle in Android while coming to foreground from homescreen :(Activity Life Cycle Methods)
onRestart()->onResume.

From the above it may seem that onRestart is similar to appWillEnterForeground,and onResume similar to appDidBecomeActive;  but we can use onRestart instead of onResume as appDidBecomeActive because :

1. onResume is called every time the app moves from one activity to
   another activity. So we better avoid Activity (ViewController)
   Specific Method. Moreover, onResume is analogous to viewWillAppear
   method in iOS.
2. onRestart method is only called when app comes to
   foreground from background, like appDidBecomeActive method, hence acts more like a app delegate method.

**Difference in both of these methods :**

onRestart() method will not be called for the very first time (at the time of App Launch) as appDidBecomeAcitve is called.

Life Cycle in iOS during app launch : (App Delegate Life Cycle Methods)
AppDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions -> *appDidBecomeActive*.

Life Cycle in Android during app launch : (Activity Life Cycle Methods)
onCreate()->onStart()->*onResume()*

Comment: Very misleading answer. Hitting the back button will trigger the previous activity's onRestart(). According to the doc: `Called after your activity has been stopped, prior to it being started again`. This has nothing to do with UIApplicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 1):

Since an app in Android is comprised of potentially multiple Activities, the equivalent of applicationDidBecomeActive is when there are no activities in running state and then one of the activities came back. The equivalent of applicationDidEnterBackground is when all of the app's activities stopped.

There is a simple way to track that with the ProcessLifecycleOwner: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner

```
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleEventObserver {
        override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    Log.i("ProcessLifecycleOwner", "app to foreground")
                }
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    Log.i("ProcessLifecycleOwner", "app to background")
                }
            }
        }
    })
```